# Calculate the Fourier transform of $\log |x| $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

How can one prove that the Fourier transform of $\log |x|$ is 
$$-\pi \mathrm{pf} \frac{1}{|\xi|} +C \delta,$$
where $\mathrm{pf}\frac{1}{|x|} = D(\mathrm{sign}(x)\log|x|)$ (in the sense of distributions) and how can I compute the constant $C$?

Comment: If I remember correctly this computation is explained very well in Folland's book on real analysis, 2nd edition, the chapter on distributions. He also makes an interesting remark on the fact that the term $C\delta$ is a "normalization" one, similar to the normalizations physicists make in QFT (where they essentially subtract infinities). If all else fails, check Tao's blog: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/#hatk (Here he computes the Fourier transform of $|x|^{-1}$ which is the derivative of $\log |x|$ )

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro In Folland, I could find the remark on quantum physics, but I cannot find the computation. Can you give me some pointers? I think that the transform of $|x|^{-s}$ is given as exercise in Tao's blog.

Comment: I am sorry, I was remembering incorrectly, the remark only concerns the definition of $|x|^{-1}$ and not its Fourier transform. See however Exercise 19, where Folland computes $\widehat{|x|^{-1}}=-\pi i \mathrm{sign}$. This computation, together with the fact that $\widehat{\log |x|}=i\xi \widehat{|x|^{-1}}$, explain the first summand in your formula for the Fourier transform. The delta summand comes from dividing by $|\xi|$ but I cannot think off the top of my head of an explanation for that.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Exactly, I agree with that. And the other problem is calculating $C$ precisely.

Comment: $C=-2\pi \gamma$, where γ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks. Could you write an answer with a proof of the result and the calculation of the constant?

Comment: Related [137994](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-log-x-xs-and-logx).

Comment: @CosmasZachos I've checked the reference, but I don't see a proof of that result. Also, that book relies on a definition of principal value integral that I would like to avoid.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, I don't have a copy of Folland's book nearby, but/and did you make a typo? Namely, the sign function is odd, and (any version of) $1/|x|$ is even, etc.

Comment: @Dal Hi Dal.   I hope that you are doing well and staying safe and healthy.  I've posted a solution that permits test functions that don't vanish at the origin.  Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: The general case in dimension $d$ is now in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723136/the-fourier-transform-of-1-p3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will start from the well-known expression (see [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Constants/EulerGamma/07/01/01/0017/)) for the Euler-Mescheroni constant $\gamma$:

$$\gamma=\int_0^1\frac{1-\cos t}{t}dt-\int_{1}^\infty\frac{\cos t}{t}dt$$
Now, if for $ x>0$ we consider
$$F(x)=\int_0^x\frac{1-\cos t}{t}dt-\int_{x}^\infty\frac{\cos t}{t}dt$$
Then we conclude from $ F(1)=\gamma$ and $F'(x)=1/x$ that
$$\eqalign{\gamma+\ln x&=
\int_0^x\frac{1-\cos t}{t}dt-\int_{x}^\infty\frac{\cos t}{t}dt\cr
&=\int_0^1\frac{1-\cos(xt)}{t}dt-\int_{1}^\infty\frac{\cos (xt)}{t}dt
}$$
And since the right side of the above formula is even we conclude that
$$
\gamma+\ln|x|=\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(t)-\cos(xt)}{t}dt\tag1
$$
For every nonzero $x$.

Let the regular distribution assosiated with the function $x\mapsto \gamma+\ln|x|$  be denoted by $T$. What is the action of $T$ on some test function $\phi$?

Indeed, if $\phi$ is a function from $\mathcal{S}$ then using $(1)$ we see that
$$\eqalign{\langle T,\phi\rangle
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\gamma+\ln|x|)\phi(x)dx\cr
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{2\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(t)\hat{\phi}(0)-\hat{\phi}(t)-\hat{\phi}(-t)}{2t}dt\cr
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{2\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(t)\hat{\phi}(0)-\hat{\phi}(t)-\check{\hat{\phi}}(t)}{2t}dt\tag2
}$$
Indeed, since
$\hat{\phi}(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)e^{-ixt}dx$ we see easily that
$$\hat{\phi}(0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)dx\quad\hbox{and}\quad
\hat{\phi}(t)+\hat{\phi}(-t)=2\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\cos(xt)dx$$
Thus, applying (2) to $\hat {\phi}$ and noting that $\hat{\hat{\phi}}=2\pi\check{\phi}$ we conclude that
$$\eqalign{\langle T,\hat{\phi}\rangle
&=2\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{2\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(t)\phi(0)-\phi(t)-\phi(-t)}{2t}dt\cr
&=\pi\int_0^1\frac{2\phi(0)-\phi(t)-\phi(-t)}{t}dt-\pi
\int_1^\infty\frac{\phi(t)+\phi(-t)}{t}dt\cr
&=\pi\int_{0}^\infty (\ln t)(\phi'(t)-\phi'(-t))dt\qquad\hbox{(integration by parts)}\cr
&=\pi\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\rm sign}(t)\ln|t|\phi'(t)dt\cr
&=-\pi\langle{\rm pf}\frac{1}{|x|},\phi\rangle
}$$
So, $\hat{T}=-\pi\,{\rm pf}\frac{1}{|x|}$. But $$\widehat{(\gamma+\ln|x|)}=2\pi\gamma\delta+\widehat{\ln|x|}$$
Thus
$$\widehat{\ln|x|}=-\pi\,{\rm pf}\frac{1}{|x|}-2\pi\gamma\delta$$
Which is the desired conclusion.

Comment: The second equality in $(2)$ is not obvious. Can you expand on it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I too would like to know about the second equality in $(2)$ and also why we conclude from $ F(1)=\gamma$ and $F'(x)=1/x$ that
$$\eqalign{\gamma+\ln x&=
\int_0^x\frac{1-\cos t}{t}dt-\int_{x}^\infty\frac{\cos t}{t}dt\cr
&=\int_0^1\frac{1-\cos(xt)}{t}dt-\int_{1}^\infty\frac{\cos (xt)}{t}dt
}$$

Comment: @Dal, $F(x)-F(1)=\int_1^x F'(t)dt$ that is $ F(x)-\gamma=\ln x$, then make the chang of variables $t\leftarrow xt$. For the second equality in $(2)$, I just multiplied both sides of $(1)$ by $\phi$ and integrated and then used the expretions of the obtained integrals in terms of the fourier transform as explained after $(2)$.

Comment: @md2perpe, please see my explaination above. Thank you.

Comment: It seems like you have switched the order of integration. How do you motivate that this is allowed?

Comment: @md2perpe, Can you justify the switch when $phi$ is finitely supported  (i.e $\phi \in \mathcal{D}$)? Is $\mathcal{D}$ a dense subspace of  $\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: @OmranKouba, you mean "$\phi$ is compactly supported". I think that $\mathscr D$ is dense in $\mathscr S$, but taking $\phi \in \mathscr D$ doesn't help. I can't see that the function $\frac{\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(t) - \cos(xt)}{t} \, \phi(x)$ belongs to $L^1((x,t) \in \mathbb R \times [0, \infty])$, and if not we can't apply the Fubini-Tonelli theorem.

Comment: @OmranKouba  Hi Omran, my friend.  I hope that you are doing well and staying safe and healthy.  I've posted a solution that permits test functions that don't vanish at the origin.  Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 10):

For this answer, we will use the Fourier Transform indicated in the question,
$$
\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,e^{-ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{FT}
$$
for which the inverse transform is
$$
f(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(\xi)\,e^{ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\tag{IFT}
$$
**Computing the Fourier Transform**

One standard way to compute the Fourier Transform of this kind of function is to multiply by $e^{-\epsilon x^2}$ and let $\epsilon\to0$.
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\epsilon x^2}\log\!|x|\,e^{-ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_0^\infty e^{-\epsilon x^2}\log(x)\,\cos(x|\xi|)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac2{|\xi|}\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_0^\infty e^{-\epsilon x^2}\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}\sin(x|\xi|)\tag{1b}\\
&=-\frac2{|\xi|}\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_0^\infty e^{-\epsilon x^2}\frac{\sin(x|\xi|)}x\,\mathrm{d}x
+\frac2{|\xi|}\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_0^\infty2\epsilon xe^{-\epsilon x^2}\log(x)\sin(x|\xi|)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1c}\\
&=-\frac\pi{|\xi|}+\frac2{|\xi|}\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_0^\infty2xe^{-x^2}(\log(x)-\log(\epsilon)/2)\sin(x|\xi|/\sqrt\epsilon)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1d}\\
&=-\frac\pi{|\xi|}+\frac2{|\xi|}\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_0^\infty2xe^{-x^2}\log(x)\sin(x|\xi|/\sqrt\epsilon)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\phantom{{}=-\frac\pi{|\xi|}}+\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{\sqrt\epsilon\log(\epsilon)}{|\xi|^2}\int_0^\infty\left(2-4x^2\right)e^{-x^2}\cos(x|\xi|/\sqrt\epsilon)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1e}\\
&=-\frac\pi{|\xi|}\tag{1f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: apply symmetry
$\text{(1b)}$: prepare to integrate by parts
$\text{(1c)}$: integrate by parts
$\text{(1d)}$: $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac\pi2$ and substitute $x\mapsto x/\sqrt\epsilon$
$\text{(1e)}$: distribute the integral over $\log(x)-\log(\epsilon)/2$
$\phantom{\text{(1e):}}$ and integrate the $\log(\epsilon)/2$ piece by parts
$\text{(1f)}$: the first integral vanishes by Riemann-Lebesgue
$\phantom{\text{(1f):}}$ the second by Riemann-Lebesgue or $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0}\sqrt\epsilon\log(\epsilon)=0$

---

**Expanding the Set of Test Functions**

$\text{(1f)}$ gives the Fourier Transform of $\log(|x|)$ when the test function vanishes at the origin. That is,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{\varphi}(x)\log(|x|)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\varphi(\xi)}{|\xi|}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\tag2
$$
Since $-\frac\pi{|\xi|}$ is not integrable near $0$, the right side of $(2)$ does not converge if $\varphi(0)\ne0$.

However, as mentioned in [Exercise 13 (Distributional interpretation of $1/|x|$)](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/#1xr) of Terry Tao's blog "245C, Notes 3: Distributions", we can evaluate principal-value tests against $\frac1{|x|}$ by computing
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{\varphi}(x)L_r(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\pi\int_{|\xi|\gt r}\frac{\varphi(\xi)}{|\xi|}\,\mathrm{d}\xi-\pi\int_{|\xi|\le r}\frac{\varphi(\xi)-\varphi(0)}{|\xi|}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\tag3
$$
If $\varphi(0)=0$, $(3)$ agrees with $(2)$, but $(3)$ converges even if $\varphi(0)\ne0$.

For any $\varphi$ so that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{\varphi}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$, $\varphi(0)=0$, so subtracting $(2)$ from $(3)$ gives
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{\varphi}(x)(L_r(x)-\log(|x|))\,\mathrm{d}x=0\tag4
$$
That is, for any $\hat\varphi$ that is orthogonal to $1$, $\hat\varphi$ is orthogonal to $L_r(x)-\log(|x|)$. Therefore, there is a constant, $\lambda_r$, so that, in the sense of distributions,
$$
\lambda_r=L_r(x)-\log(|x|)\tag5
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2\pi}r\varphi(0)
&=\partial_r\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{\varphi}(x)L_r(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{6a}\\
&=\partial_r\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{\varphi}(x)(L_r(x)-\log(|x|))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{6b}\\
&=\partial_r\lambda_r\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{\varphi}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{6c}\\[6pt]
&=\partial_r\lambda_r2\pi\varphi(0)\tag{6d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(6a)}$: take the derivative of $(3)$
$\text{(6b)}$: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{\varphi}(x)\log(|x|)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is constant in $r$
$\text{(6c)}$: apply $(5)$
$\text{(6d)}$: apply $\text{(IFT)}$

Therefore, for some constant $K$,
$$
\lambda_r=K+\log(r)\tag7
$$

---

**Computing $\boldsymbol{K}$**

Use $\varphi(\xi)=e^{-\xi^2/2}$ and $\hat\varphi(x)=\sqrt{2\pi}\,e^{-x^2/2}$ in $(3)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}L_r(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\pi\int_{|\xi|\gt r}\frac{e^{-\xi^2/2}}{|\xi|}\,\mathrm{d}\xi-\pi\int_{|\xi|\le r}\frac{e^{-\xi^2/2}-1}{|\xi|}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\tag{8a}\\
&=\pi\log\left(r^2/2\right)+\pi\gamma\tag{8b}
\end{align}
$$
and in the left hand side of $(2)$:
$$
\sqrt{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\log(|x|)\,\mathrm{d}x=\pi(-\gamma-\log(2))\tag9
$$
Subtracting $(9)$ from $(8)$ and applying $(5)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\pi\log\left(r^2\right)+2\pi\gamma
&=\sqrt{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,\overbrace{(L_r(x)-\log(|x|))}^{\lambda_r}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{10a}\\
&=2\pi\lambda_r\tag{10b}
\end{align}
$$
from which we get
$$
\lambda_r=\gamma+\log(r)\tag{11}
$$
That is, $K=\gamma$, the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

---

**Conclusion**

Equations $(5)$ and $(11)$ say that $L_r(x)-\log(x)=\gamma+\log(r)$; therefore, $(3)$ can be written as
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat\varphi(x)\overbrace{(\log(|x|)+\gamma+\log(r))}^{L_r(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=-\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\varphi(\xi)-\varphi(0)[|\xi|\lt r]}{|\xi|}\,\mathrm{d}\xi\tag{12}
$$
$\text{(FT)}$ says that $\hat\delta=1$ and $\text{(IFT)}$ says that $\hat1=2\pi\delta$. Setting $C_r=-2\pi(\gamma+\log(r))$ and $\varphi_r(\xi)=\varphi(\xi)-\varphi(0)[|\xi|\lt r]$, where $[\dots]$ are [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat\varphi(x)\log(|x|)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\left(-\frac\pi{|\xi|}\right)\varphi_r(\xi)+C_r\delta(\xi)\varphi(\xi)\right)\mathrm{d}\xi\tag{13}
$$
Thus, depending on the $r$ we choose in $(3)$, we get a different $C_r$ in $(13)$. If we choose $r=1$, we get $C_r=-2\pi\gamma$, which is the $C$ obtained by Omran Kouba. If we choose $r=e^{-\gamma}$, then we get $C_r=0$, which removes the need for a delta function. However, no choice of $r$ removes the need for using $\varphi_r$ to permit dividing by $|\xi|$ while retaining integrability.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very educational. But do you also know how to solve the problem as originally posed?

Comment: @Robjohn How the Fourier transform of $\log|x|$ where $x\in R^2$? Is it $1/|\xi|^2$?

Comment: @BobOakley: Using this normalization of the Fourier Transform, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, away from $0$, $$\mathscr{F}(\log(|x|))=-\frac{\pi^{(n+1)/2}}{|\xi|^n}\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}$$

Comment: @robjohn Yes, I forgot the absolute value.  Perhaps you are thinking of the classical principal value.  Here it is in the distributional sense $\psi=\text{PV}\left(\frac1{|x|}\right)$ is defined as $$\langle \psi,\phi \rangle =\int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{\phi(x)}{|x|}\,dx+\int_{|x|\le 1}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{|x|}\,dx$$

Comment: Then would $\delta$ be applied to $\phi(x)-\phi(0)$ since $\delta$ is $0$ for $|x|\ge1$?

Comment: No.  The $\delta $ contribution is in addition to this.  See [THIS}(https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300024/about-the-fourier-transform-of-the-logarithm-function) for example.

Comment: As is mentioned in [Exercise 13](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/#1xr), depending on how big of an interval we use there (and which normalization of the Fourier Transform, I imagine), we get a different constant times $\delta$. Since *neither* of these are specified in the question, it seems odd to then claim a certain constant is the correct one.

Comment: Yes, one need not use $|x|=1$ as a dividing point.  It is arbitrary and one could have chosen any number, say $\nu >0$.  But inasmuch as $\log(1)=0$, it seems a reasonable choice.  With $\nu\ne 1$, then the coefficient on the Dirac Delta is augmented by an additive factor of $\pi \log(\nu)$ (if I am doing the arithmetic in my head correctly).  So, the point is that there is a Dirac Delta contribution and that the $\psi(x)=\frac1{|x|}$ term is interpreted in distribution as $$\langle \psi, \phi\rangle =\int_{|x|<\nu}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{|x|}\,dx+\int_{|x|>\nu}\frac{\phi(x)}{|x|}\,dx$$

Comment: @robjohn Hi Rob.  I've just posted a solution that might be of interest.  As always, I value your thoughts.

Comment: @MarkViola: The cutoff at $1$ seemed too arbitrary, so I have extended my answer quite a bit using ideas from Terry Tao's blog to investigate the effect of different cutoffs (although I have shortened the original part of the answer).

Comment: Hi Rob.  Did you read my posted solution?  I covered the case of arbitrary cutoff.   In fact, $\nu =1$ is not a bad choice as it gets rid of the $\log(\nu)$ term of the Dirac Delta.

Comment: I worked on mine offline off and on for the last week. I didn't get to read yours until after I posted this. I will comment.  I kind of like that cutting off at $e^{-\gamma}$ gets rid of the $\delta$ term altogether.

Comment: The integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log(|x|) \hat \phi(x)\,dx$ exists as an improper Riemann integral.  And as I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-log-x-xs-and-logx/4113196#4113196), we have $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log(|x|) \hat \phi(x)\,dx=-2\pi (\gamma +\log(r))\phi(0)+\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(k) - \phi(0) \xi_{[-r,r]}(k)}{|k|}\,dk$$So, what does $L_r(x)$ represent here?

Comment: $L_r(x)=\log(|x|)+\gamma+\log(r)$. When the constant $\gamma+\log(r)$ is integrated against $\hat\phi(x)$ we get $2\pi\phi(0)(\gamma+\log(r))$, which appears subtracted from the right side in your integral.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, such computations are standard, but/and can be done in several ways. One approach is to first observe that ${d\over dx}(\log|x|)$ is the principal-value integral $u$ against $1/x$ (not $1/|x|$). This principal value integral is not a literal integrate-against functional, since $1/x$ is not locally integrable (nor is $1/|x|$). Even though it's not a literal integral, one still shows directly that $x\cdot u = 1$, where on the left multiplication by the smooth function (of moderate growth...) on tempered distributions is as usual. (We simply cannot "divide" in a pointwise sense.)

Fourier transform has an easily-verified effect on positive-homogeneity, and parity: the FT of $|x|^{-s}$ is a constant multiple of $|x|^{1-s}$, literally so for $0<\Re(s)<1$, and then by meromorphic continuation. Thus, the Fourier transform of $u$ is a constant multiple of $\mathrm{sgn}\,x$. By integrating against $xe^{-\pi x^2}$, for example (or almost any other odd Schwartz function) one finds that the constant is $-i\pi$ (maybe!).

Thus, letting $F$ be Fourier transform, 
$$
-i\pi \mathrm{sgn}\,x \;=\; F u \;=\; F{d\over dx}\log|\cdot|
\;=\; -2\pi ix \cdot F\log|\cdot|
$$
Thus, $2x\cdot F\log|\cdot|= \mathrm{sgn}\,x$. Again, we cannot quite divide pointwise. However, the kernel of the multiplication-by-$x$ operator on tempered distributions consists of distributions supported at $\{0\}$, which (essentially by the theory of Taylor-Maclaurin series) is just finite linear combinations of Dirac $\delta$ and its derivatives. Further, the only such linear combination annihilated by mult'n by $x$ are just multiples of $\delta$ itself. Thus, the relation $2x\cdot F\log|\cdot|=\mathrm{sgn}\,x$ determines that Fourier transform up to multiples of $\delta$.

To determine the constant, let $g(x)=e^{-\pi x^2}$, for example, and for arbitrary Schwartz function $f$, use the standard trick
$$
v(f) \;=\; v(f-f(0)\cdot g)+f(0)v(g)
$$
and then evaluate $v(f-f(0)g)$ by using the literal integral definition, since $f-f(0)g$ vanishes at $0$, etc.

EDIT: per request of the questioner, I'll give the determination-of-constant idea (in principle standard, but... etc) in further detail, though I would have to think more to express it in terms of the Euler-Mascheroni constant, etc.

That is, let $u=\widehat \log|\cdot|$. Suppose we know that $x\cdot u=a\cdot \mathrm{sgn}\,x$, where I've written another constant $a$ to accommodate possible earlier boo-boos, and make it easier to track. Also note that for a test function $f$, if $f(0)=0$, then $f(x)/x$ is also a test function. Let $g$ be the Gaussian, as above. Then $f(x)-f(0)\cdot g(x)$ is of the form $x\cdot h(x)$ for a test function $h$. Thus,
$$
u(f) \;=\; u(f-f(0)g)+f(0)u(g)
\;=\; u(x\cdot {f-f(0)g\over x}) + \delta f \cdot u(g)
\;=\; (x\cdot u)({f-f(0)g\over x}) + \delta f\cdot u(g)
$$
$$
\;=\; a\int \mathrm{sgn}\,(x)\cdot {f(x)-f(0)g(x)\over x}\;dx + \delta f\cdot u(g)
\;=\; a\int {f(x)-f(0)g(x)\over |x|}\;dx + \delta f\cdot u(g)
$$
The integral can be further explicated in various ways, e.g., integrating by parts. The most-unknown part of the business is the constant $u(g)$, which appears (maybe part of) the coefficient of $\delta$.

Edit-Edit: in response to some further questions: to see the vanishing at $0$ of $f-f(0)g$:
$$
f(0)-f(0)\cdot g(0) \;=\; f(0) - f(0)\cdot 1 \;=\; 0
$$
The fact that 
$$
u(f) \;=\; u(f-f(0)g+f(0)g)\;=\;u(f-f(0)\cdot g) + u(f(0)\cdot g)
\;=\; u(f-f(0)\cdot g) + f(0)\cdot u(g)
$$
is the linearity of $u$. As to evaluating the constant which involves the Euler-Mascheroni constant, I do not have an easy answer. But the literal integral can be manipulated in several ways, for example integrating by parts, to get something like your 'pf' functional.

Comment: The part of your answer with the calculation of the constant is not clear to me. Could you carry it out in detail?

Comment: To be honest, your additional details didn't clear the matter for me: 1. why does $f - f(0)g$ does vanish at $0$? 2. why $u(f) = u(f-f(0)g)+f(0)u(g)$? 3. How do those step help in finding the constant in the expression I wrote in the question? 4. How does one find out the value of the constant and the integral in the last line of your calculations?

Comment: 1. Since $g(x)=e^{-\pi x^2}$ we have $g(0) = 1$ so $f(0) - f(0) g(0) = f(0) - f(0) \cdot 1= 0$. 2. We have $f = f - f(0)g + f(0)g$ and with $u$ linear this implies $u(f) = u(f - f(0)g + f(0)g) = u(f - f(0)g) + u(f(0)g) = u(f - f(0)g) + f(0) u(g)$.

Comment: @paulgarrett Hi Paul, my friend.  I hope that you are doing well and staying safe and healthy.  I've posted a solution that permits test functions that don't vanish at the origin.  Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

**I thought that it might be instructive to present an approach to deriving the Fourier transform of $\log(|x|)$ that uses a regularization approach.  This way forward is distinct from the methodology I used in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-log-x-xs-and-logx/4113196#4113196).**

**The result herein includes a distributional interpretation of $\frac1{|x|}$.  Finally, we show that the distributional interpretation of $\frac1{|x|}$ is non-unique and that it differs from other interpretations by a multiple of the Dirac Delta distribution.  With that introduction, we now proceed.**

---

---

**PRELIMARIES**

Let $\psi(x)=\log(|x|)$ and let $\Psi$ denote its Fourier Transform .  Then, we write

$$\Psi(x)=\mathscr{F}\{\psi\}(x)\tag 1$$

where $(1)$ is interpreted as a Tempered Distribution.  That is, for any $\phi \in \mathbb{S}$, we can write

$$\langle \mathscr{F}\{\psi\}, \phi\rangle =\langle \psi, \mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle$$

Now, let $\psi_\epsilon(k) =e^{-\varepsilon|k|}\log(|k|)$.  Therefore, $\psi(k)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\psi_\varepsilon(k)$ and we see that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\langle \mathscr{F}\{\psi_\varepsilon\}, \phi\rangle&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\langle \psi_\varepsilon, \mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle \\\\
&=\langle \psi,\mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\langle \mathscr{F}\{\psi\}, \phi\rangle
\end{align}$$

Next, we evaluate the Fourier transform of $\psi_\varepsilon$.

---

---

**EVALUATING THE FOURIER TRANSFORM OF $\displaystyle \psi_\varepsilon$**

Denote by $\Psi_\epsilon$, the Fourier transform of $\psi_\varepsilon$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\Psi_\varepsilon(x)&=\mathscr{F}\{\psi_\epsilon\}(x)\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\varepsilon|k|}\log(|k|) e^{ikx}\,dk\\\\
&=2\text{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-(\varepsilon -ix)k}\log(k) \,dk\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{2\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\gamma -\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\log(\varepsilon^2+x^2)-\frac{2x}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\arctan(x/\varepsilon)\\\\
&=\psi^{(1)}_\varepsilon(x)+\psi^{(2)}_\varepsilon(x)+\psi^{(3)}_\varepsilon(x)\tag2
\end{align}$$

where

$$\begin{align}
\psi^{(1)}_\varepsilon(x)&=-\frac{2\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\gamma\\\\
\psi^{(2)}_\varepsilon(x)&=-\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\log(\varepsilon^2+x^2)\\\\
\psi^{(3)}_\varepsilon(x)&=-\frac{2x}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\arctan(x/\varepsilon)
\end{align}$$

Next, we will find the distributional limits of $\psi^{(1)}_\varepsilon$, $\psi^{(2)}_\varepsilon$, and $\psi^{(3)}_\varepsilon$.

---

**DISTRIBUTIONAL LIMITS OF $\displaystyle \psi^{(1)}_\varepsilon$, $\displaystyle 
 \psi^{(2)}_\varepsilon$, and $\displaystyle  \psi^{(3)}_\varepsilon$**

Again, let $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\langle \psi^{(1)}_\varepsilon,\phi \rangle &=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi^{(1)}_\varepsilon(x)\phi(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(-\frac{2\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\gamma \right)\phi(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-2\gamma\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(\varepsilon x)}{x^2+1}\,dx\\\\
&=-2\pi \gamma \phi(0)\tag3
\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\langle \psi^{(2)}_\varepsilon,\phi \rangle &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(-\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\log(\varepsilon^2+x^2) \right)\phi(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-2\log(\varepsilon)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(\varepsilon x)}{x^2+1}\,dx-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\phi(\varepsilon x)\,dx\\\\
&= -2\pi \log(\varepsilon)\phi(0)-2\pi \log(2) \phi(0)+o(\varepsilon)
\end{align}\tag4$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\langle \psi^{(3)}_\varepsilon,\phi \rangle &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(-\frac{2x}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\arctan(x/\varepsilon)\right)\phi(x)\,dx\\\\
&-\int_{|x|\le 1}\frac{2x}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\arctan(x/\varepsilon) \phi(x)\,dx-\int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{2x}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\arctan(x/\varepsilon) \phi(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\phi(0)\int_{|x|\le 1}\frac{2x}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\arctan(x/\varepsilon) \,dx\\\\
&-\int_{|x|\le 1}\frac{2x}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\arctan(x/\varepsilon) (\phi(x)-\phi(0))\,dx-\int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{2x}{\varepsilon^2+x^2}\arctan(x/\varepsilon) \phi(x)\,dx\\\\
&= \left(2\pi \log(\varepsilon) +2\pi \log(2)\right)\phi(0)+o(\varepsilon)\\\\
&-\pi \int_{|x|\le 1}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{|x|}\,dx-\pi \int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{\phi(x)}{|x|}\,dx\tag5
\end{align}$$

---

---

**FINAL RESULTS**

Substituting $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$ into $(2)$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\langle \mathscr{F}\{\psi_\varepsilon\},\phi\rangle =-2\pi \gamma \phi(0)-\pi \int_{|x|\le 1}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{|x|}\,dx-\pi\int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{\phi(x)}{|x|}\,dx\\\\
\end{align}$$

from which we assert that in distribution

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000] {\mathscr{F}\{\psi\}(x)=-2\pi \gamma \delta(x)-\pi \left(\frac1{|x|}\right)_1}$$

where we interpret $\left(\frac1{|x|}\right)_1$ to mean that for any $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \left(\frac1{|x|}\right)_1 \phi(x)\,dx=\int_{|x|\le 1}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{|x|}\,dx+ \int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{\phi(x)}{|x|}\,dx$$

---

---

**NOTE:**

It was arbitrary to split the integration in $(5)$ into inervals $|x|\le 1$ and $|x|\ge 1$.  Had we chosen instead the intervals $|x|\le \nu$ and $|x|\ge \nu$ for any $\nu>0$, we would have obtained

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000] {\mathscr{F}\{\psi\}(x)=-2\pi (\gamma+\log(\nu)) \delta(x)-\pi \left(\frac1{|x|}\right)_\nu}$$

where we interpret $\left(\frac1{|x|}\right)_\nu$ to mean that for any $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \left(\frac1{|x|}\right)_\nu \phi(x)\,dx=\int_{|x|\le \nu}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{|x|}\,dx+ \int_{|x|\ge \nu}\frac{\phi(x)}{|x|}\,dx$$

Comment: Our methods are similar in that we use the standard distributional definition of the Fourier Transform (modified Plancherel). You used $e^{-|x|}$, which works fine, but requires more ancillary functions than using $e^{-x^2/2}$. I'll have to look more closely at $(2)$ on. It looks as if we both got the same result, so that's good confirmation.

Comment: @robjohn I've posted another solution to develop the Fourier Transform of $\log(|x|)$ [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-log-x-xs-and-logx/4113196#4113196).  Instead of regularizing $\log(|x|)$ as we did herin, I directly evaluate the functional $$\langle \mathscr{F}\{\log(|x|)\}, \phi\rangle =\langle \log(|x|), \mathscr{F}\{\phi\} \rangle =\int_0^\infty \log(x) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k) e^{ikx}\,dk\,dx$$Soiler alert ... we get the same result!

Comment: I had just noticed that post and was about to mention that here, but you beat me to it.

Comment: @robjohn It's unfortunate that MSE cannot consolidate distinct solutions posted as responses to similar questions.  I could post both of my solutions to both questions, but unsure about the protocols on MSE.

Comment: Rather than copying different answers, it might be better to provide links to other answers (as long as they’re on StackExchange).

Comment: I've done that now

Comment: The $D$ form can be obtained in a slightly simpler way. If $f(x) = i (\ln^2(a + i x) - \ln^2(a - i x))/2$, then $\lim_{a \to 0^+} \psi_a(x)$, $\lim_{a \to 0^+} f(x)$, $\mathcal F[\psi_a]$ and $f'$ are the same in the distributional sense and in the ordinary sense. Since the distributional FT and the distributional derivative are continuous,
$$\mathcal F[\psi](x) =
\lim_{a \to 0^+} \left( f'(x) -\frac {2 \gamma a} {x^2 + a^2} \right), \\
\lim_{a \to 0^+} f'(x) =
\frac d {dx} (-\pi \ln(|x|) \operatorname {sgn} x).$$

Comment: Because it's relevant to your answer? :) $f'(x) - 2 \gamma a/(x^2 + a^2)$ is the same as $\Psi_a(x)$. The question defines $1/|x|$ as the distributional derivative of the regular distribution $\ln(|x|) \operatorname {sgn} x$, which is exactly what we obtain.

Comment: What is $f$?  And we are asked to find the Fourier transform of $\log(|x|)$, which is a locally integrable function and hence a distribution.  We are not interested here in the FT of $\log(|x|)\text{sgn}(x)$.  So, I am still uncertain as to the way forward.  Perhaps you could post your suggested solution and add the details that are difficult to include in a comment.

Comment: @Maxim Perhaps the simpler way is to use the approach I used in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-log-x-xs-and-logx/4113196#4113196)

Comment: $f$ is defined in my first comment, $\psi, \psi_a, \Psi_a$ are defined in your answer. So
$$\mathcal F \big[ k \mapsto \ln |k| \big](x) =
-\pi \frac d {dx} (\ln(|x|) \operatorname {sgn} x) -
 \lim_{a \to 0^+} \frac {2 \gamma a} {x^2 + a^2},$$
there is nothing about the FT of $\ln(|x|) \operatorname {sgn} x$.

Comment: How are you interpreting $\frac{d}{dx}\left( \log(|x|) \text{sgn}(x)\right)$?  Is that a distributional derivative?  And have you checked out the other solution I posted and referenced?

Comment: No, I haven't looked at the linked answer. $d(\ln(|x|) \operatorname {sgn} x)/dx$ is the distributional derivative, which is why it can be interchanged with the distributional limit, as my first comment says.

Comment: From where did you get the identity used in equation (2), i.e. where you go from an integral to a sum with three terms?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\ln\pars{\verts{x}} =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{\mrm{f}}\pars{k}
\expo{\ic kx}\,{\dd k \over 2\pi}}$.

---

\begin{align}
\hat{\mrm{f}}\pars{k} & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\ln\pars{\verts{x}}\expo{-\ic kx}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}
\cos\pars{\verts{k}x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
2\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}
\expo{\ic\verts{k}x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\left.2\,\Re\,\partiald{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{\infty}
x^{\nu - 1}\expo{\ic\verts{k}x}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ 1}
\end{align}
Note that
$$
\expo{\ic\verts{k}x} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{\ic\verts{k}x}^{n} \over n!} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\color{red}{\expo{-\ic \pi n/2}\,\,\verts{k}^{n}}\,
{\pars{-x}^{n}\over n!}
$$

With
[Ramanujan's Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem):
\begin{align}
\hat{\mrm{f}}\pars{k} & =
\left.2\,\Re\,\partiald{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{\infty}
x^{\nu - 1}\,\expo{\ic\verts{k}x}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.2\,\Re\,\partiald{}{\nu}\bracks{%
\Gamma\pars{\nu}\expo{\ic\pi\nu/2}
\,\verts{k}^{-\nu}}
\,\right\vert_{\ \nu\ =\ 1}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{-\,{\pi \over \verts{k}}} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Hi Felix my friend.  I hope that you are doing well and staying safe and healthy.  I've posted a solution that permits test functions that don't vanish at the origin.  Please let me know your thoughts.