# How to integrate this type of integral: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\int_ 0^1}\frac{n x^{n-1}}{1+x}dx$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

What should be the strategy to solve these type of integrals. And how to solve this integral.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\int_ 0^1}\frac{n x^{n-1}}{1+x}dx$

I tried to solve it by substitution: multiplying and deviding by $x^n$ and substibution $t=x^n$  I got this

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\int_ 0^1}\frac{1}{1+x^{1/n}}dx$

and don't know what to do now.

Comment: See also: [Limit of $s_n = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x} dx$ as $n \to \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/292251)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that: $$\int_ 0^1\frac{n x^{n-1}}{1+x}dx=\left.\frac{x^n}{1+x}\right|_{0}^{1} +{\int_ 0^1}\frac{x^{n}}{(1+x)^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}+{\int_ 0^1}\frac{x^{n}}{(1+x)^2}dx$$
Furthermore:
$$0\leq\int_ 0^1\frac{x^{n}}{(1+x)^2}dx\leq\int_ 0^1x^ndx=\frac{1}{n+1}$$

As $n\rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{1}{n+1}\rightarrow 0$ so the original integral $\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$ by squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac 1 {1+x}\,d(x^n)=\int_0^1\frac 1 {1+x^2}\,du(x)=\frac 1 {1+1}=\frac 1 2$$ where $u(x)=I(x=1)$.

Comment: how did you came to second step, I didn't understand.

Comment: how did you removed lim please explain

Comment: @Git $d(x^n)$ converges to $du(x)$ in distribution.

Comment: is u(x) is a function?

Comment: It is, but it's more important that it's defined a distribution on $[0,1]$.

Comment: This approach is quite likely passing *largely* over the OP's head (and is not necessary at all).

Comment: @Did Which *essentially* different method is there?

Comment: See other answer.

Comment: @GiteshwarMali: you can move the limit under the integral sign in this case: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120768/moving-a-limit-inside-an-integral?rq=1