# Infinite Integration of Bessel Function of the First Order and Zero Degree

Tags: calculus, integration, laplace-transform, bessel-functions

I want to prove that 
$$\int_0^\infty J_0(bx)dx=\frac1b \tag{1} $$
What I have found online is that you take the Laplace Transform of the Bessel Function and we get
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}J_0(bx)dx=\frac1{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \tag{2} $$
and we set $a=0$. However, for the derivation of the above result I have assumed that $a>0$, so that during the integration on the infinite end the integrant goes to zero.
$$ I=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^\infty dx\int_{-\pi}^\pi d\theta \cdot e^{(ib\sin \theta-a)x}=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{d\theta}{a-ib\sin\theta}=\cdots$$
For the proof of $(1)$ we have to take $a=0$. How can we justify this substitution or even the $a\rightarrow ia$?

Comment: If $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm dx $ exists as an improper Riemann integral, then $$\lim_{a \to 0^{+}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} f(x) \, \mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) \, \mathrm dx$$  See Daniel Fischer's answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120768) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1519281).